# Cuda Shared memory shown as register in Nsight

Tags: cuda, nsight, gpu-shared-memory

I declared shared memory and tried to trace it with  Nsight 2.2 for Visual Studio 2010. I'm using CUDA 4.2 with a Quadro 5000.

in my kernel.cu:

```
extern __shared__ ushort2 sampleGatheringSM[];
```

The code launching the kernel:

```
sampleGathering_SM_size =dimBlock.x*dimBlock.y*4*sizeof(ushort2)*2; // = 10240
sampleGatheringKernel<<<dimGrid, dimBlock, sampleGathering_SM_size >>>(dev_image, dev_gradient, width, height);
```

When I look at the analysis activity on Nsight then "CUDA Launches", it tells me that:

- Allocated Registers per block: 10240
- Allocated Shared Memory per block: 0
- Block Limit Reason: Registers

Did I allocate shared memory correctly?
I don't understand how I could allocate registers.

EDIT:

It also tells me:

- Register per threads: 32
- Dynamic Shared memory per block: 0
- Static shared memory per block: 0

Comment: The declaration of sampleGatheringSM[] appears to be correct (missing the full code to verify). The CUDA Launches table should show Registers per Thread (0-63), Static Shared Memory per Block = ? (insufficient detail in description), Dynamic Shared Memory per Block (10240) based upon the 3rd argument in <<<>>>. In which UI do you see the terms "Allocated Registers per block"? The only location I'm aware of is the CUDA Occupancy pane has the row Registers/Block. I will file a bug to the team to investigate the issue.

Comment: The Allocated Registers Per Block is a far column on the right. Sorry I forgot the value was repeated twice. I've reproduced the problem locally.

Comment: The Allocated Registers per Block is correct. dimBlock.x * dimBlock.y * 32 registers per thread is 10240. On an internal version of Nsight I can reproduce Dynamic Shared Memory = 0 for a CUDA trace activity. The correct value is reported for a CUDA profile activity. Static shared memory per block is correct for both activities.

Comment: @GregSmith When you said " CUDA profile activity", do you mean that you used visual profiler instead of Nsight ? So the bug is from Nsight ? As I didn't use Static Shared memory, I couldn't test it. I don't know if it matters but `extern __shared__ ushort2 sampleGatheringSM[]` is declared outside the global function in global in the file.

Comment: @GregSmith Also, I have modified my program and have now 53 registers, As I have 320 threads per block I should get 320*53=16960 bytes of memory allocated for registers. But it tells me that I have 17280 bytes allocated (320*54). There is one register missing.

Comment: The CUDA Profile activity is an Analysis activity option found on the Analysis Activity page.

Comment: @JeffDavis ok, thank's. I can now see the correct "allocated shared memory per block".

Comment: @Seltymar Each device architecture has a different algorithm for allocating registers. Fermi architecture allocates registers per warp at a granularity of 64 registers (or 2 registers/thread). The tool reports both the number of registers per thread used by the compiler as well as the number of registers allocated per block. The second calculation includes the register allocation logic resulting in 54 registers per thread. The allocation granularity for registers is documented in the CUDA Occupancy Calculator (.xls) GPU Data worksheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration of dynamic shared memory is correct. Nsight 2.2 Analysis Trace Report has a bug that only occurs for CUDA Trace Activities. Analysis Trace Activities run with the option **Nsight** | **Options**| **Analysis** | **CUDA Kernel Trace Mode** = **Serialized** and Analysis Profiler CUDA Activities display the correct value. This bug will be fixed in the next version of Nsight.